# Used Keurig smells and tastes like cigarettes

Tags: cleaning, keurig

I was recently given a used Keurig from a relative. Unfortunately this person was a heavy smoker. I ran vinegar through the machine as well as removed and rinsed the little cup that holds the k-cups, but it still smells and tastes like tobacco. What can I do?

Comment: Reminds me how [the inventor of the K-Cup®, John Sylvan, said](https://coffeeinformer.com/are-k-cups-bad-for-you/) they're "like a cigarette for coffee"…

Answer (score 8):

First of all, note that the smell of the machine itself is unlikely to come from the interior of the parts that heat and transport water -- after all, they are regularly cleaned with hot water and smoke has a hard time getting there.

So running vinegar through the machine won't change that. Rather, it is the other surfaces that cause problems. Thoroughly cleaning *all* surfaces of the machine may help a little bit (including the easily accessible ones behind the cover), and storing it in a room that is thoroughly aired for some months should also help to some extent. Depending on the temperature, a garage may also be an option. You need to be careful to not break the machine during cleaning and airing, though.

Answer (score 3):

Pass it to your local authority's electrical recycling scheme, then purchase a new one.

Comment: @jen ...And buy an Aeropress ^_^ Actually another good idea is to try to scrub it with a Baking Soda wash. Baking Soda is a good odor eater but If all else fails, it might be time to retire this unit.